# Compatibility of Taipy with Python3.11.1

Tags: version, compatibility, taipy

When installing Taipy using Python 3.11.1 the installer backs out during the installation of the greenlet package. The error is as follows:

building ‘greenlet._greenlet’ extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with “Microsoft C++ Build Tools”: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
[end of output]

Installing Greenlet separately or installing the Visual Studio build Tools does not solve the issue.

Reverting to Python 3.10.9 solves the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work now in the lastest version of Taipy (2.2).